# C# Textbox has initial text, but if user changes it store the change

Tags: c#

So I have a textbox I'm using to store the URL of a server. Though this could potentially change at anytime, so I would like the text box to store the current URL initially...`http://example/`. But when the server URL changes I would like the user to be able to edit this textbox to say `http://newurl/` and for the textbox to remember this change next time the program starts up. Is there a simple way to do this in C#, is this something I can even do?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this. It boils down to loading either the default value or a user specific value from a data store (could be as simple as a settings file on up to a database).

#### Resources for Settings:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755.aspx

I just googled "settings MSDN". There is a lot more information out there on Settings, as well as your other options for persistent storage. The choice is highly dependent on the size and scale of your application, so you'll have to make that decision yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to persist the value on shutdown *somehow*. Common options are:

- Just files (of whatever format, e.g. XML)
- [User settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx)
- A database
- Some sort of remote storage

We can't really tell which of those is most appropriate. User settings may well be the simplest. You should probably consider saving these on either form close or application exit; then when your app starts you need to load any settings which have been persisted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Settings file.  When the program is closing,

```
Properties.Settings.Default.URL = URLTextbox.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Then on your load event:

```
URLTextbox.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is in general persistency. Your options include storing the string in a file, in the registry or in a database. There are probably other options, but those 3 are the most common ones.